# IIS - AppPool StartMode changing by itself

Tags: c#, windows, iis, .net-5

On my developer machine, amongst my 10 websites and their respective application pools, three of them are very frequently getting setted to startMode = Always running.

I have to reset them to OnDemand regularly and I cannot find the root cause of this.

Apps are coded in C# using .Net5 and hosted on IIS 10

Below is an exemple log from the Event Logs showing the change

```xml
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
    <System>
      <Provider Name="Microsoft-Windows-IIS-Configuration" Guid="{dc0b8e51-4863-407a-bc3c-1b479b2978ac}" /> 
      <EventID>29</EventID> 
      <Version>0</Version> 
      <Level>5</Level> 
      <Task>0</Task> 
      <Opcode>0</Opcode> 
      <Keywords>0x4000000000000000</Keywords> 
      <TimeCreated SystemTime="2022-06-20T15:25:46.2192842Z" /> 
      <EventRecordID>5</EventRecordID> 
      <Correlation /> 
      <Execution ProcessID="10120" ThreadID="10800" /> 
      <Channel>Microsoft-IIS-Configuration/Operational</Channel> 
      <Computer>LAP-PLS</Computer> 
      <Security UserID="S-1-5-21-2179824267-3666241482-379869353-1001" /> 
    </System>
    <EventData>
      <Data Name="PhysicalPath">\\?\C:\WINDOWS\system32\inetsrv\config\applicationHost.config</Data> 
      <Data Name="ConfigPath">MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST</Data> 
      <Data Name="EffectiveLocationPath" /> 
      <Data Name="Configuration">/system.applicationHost/applicationPools/add[@name="XXXX"]/@startMode</Data> 
      <Data Name="EditOperationType">3</Data> 
      <Data Name="OldValue">OnDemand</Data> 
      <Data Name="NewValue">AlwaysRunning</Data> 
    </EventData>
</Event>
```

This is driving me crazy and help would me much appreciated

Thanks,

Comment: You can try the following settings, and then check if the state of StartMode still changes: Right click the application node and select Manage Application > Advanced Settings. Set Preload Enabled to True. To figure out the reason for the change, you need to check the changes in the application pool, you can try to Monitor IIS Configuration change using Event Logs, If there is no useful information in Event Logs, you need to use some other tools.

Comment: hi @samwu, thanks for your answer. There appears to be no such thing as "Preload Enabled" on IIS10. I have logs, but it does not help me determine the source of the issue.

I'll add an exemple log to my original question maybe you know what to look for in it

Comment: There is no application pool configuration change record in the log, and there seems to be no Preload Enabled setting in the advanced settings of the iis10 application pool, but you can set it in applicationHost.config file(`%WINDIR%\system32\inetsrv\config\applicationHost`).

Comment: `There is no application pool configuration change record in the log`
How can you say that ???
      <Data Name="OldValue">OnDemand</Data> 
      <Data Name="NewValue">AlwaysRunning</Data>